# Understanding the get-culture command

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, windows-server-2012, cultureinfo, culture

I recently had some trouble with culture dependent returned values from my powershell script. The same script returned different values, depending on which machine it was.
So I thought that maybe the culture settings are different and for one server it returned.

```
get-culture : de-DE
```

for the other it was like : `en-US`

One value is for the keyboard settings but what does the other (second) stand for?

And is the second value bound to the OS installation or is that just a setting?
Is there a command in powershell to change the value?

Of course I first read the gelp `get-help get-culture`

```
DESCRIPTION
    The Get-Culture cmdlet gets information about the current culture settings. This includes information about the
    current language settings on the system, such as the keyboard layout, and the display format of items such as
    numbers, currency, and dates.
```

But I am not satisfied with it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233967.aspx

Comment: I only see one field being returned, Name. de-DE is German German (as opposed to Austrian or Swiss German). en-US is US English. It is unclear what exactly you are asking. Apparently there is a Set-Culture cmdlet in the international module though.

Comment: so, asking another way. Is it possible to set it to de-US ? I thought the first code is for keyboard layout and the second one maybe for system internal settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The help for the Cmdlet **Get-Culture** contains a subheading name *related links*. Please note the last 2 lines.

> **Related Links** 
>   Online Version: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=293965 
>   Set-Culture 
>   Get-UICulture

When searching for help also use the **Get-Command** Cmdlet.

```
Get-Command "*culture*"
```

You can view your 'current culture' by using the built in **Powershell** variables.

```
$PSCulture
$PSUICulture
```

---

The following code block returns the short date pattern of three different cultures.

```
### Creates an array of cultureinfo objects:
$myCulturesArray = @(    
    ( $myDECulture = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE") ),
    ( $myGBCulture = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB") ),
    ( $myUSCulture = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US") )
);

### Outputs today's date using each CultureInfo object
$myCulturesArray | foreach { 
  (Get-date).ToString('d', $_ ) 
}
```

Further reading:

Tobias Weltner put together a very useful set of [pdfs](http://powershell.com/cs/media/g/powertipsmonthly2013/default.aspx), volume 3 is on culture. 
 
Also, at the prompt:

```
Get-Help Get-Culture -Full
help about_Script_Internationalization
```