# Need Help convert scientific number from JSON

Tags: powershell

Hy,

I am trying to get a value from a JSON file. Value is stored like this: `"3,4488636215177E-12"`.

I've never used PowerShell before.

I try this:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://api.minerstat.com/v2/coins?list=BTC,ETH,ETC" | ConvertFrom-Json) | ? coin | select reward,price,coin | epcsv minerstat.csv -not

$Minerstat = import-csv -Path ".\minerstat.csv" -Delimiter ","

$ETH_reward = $Minerstat | where{$_.coin -eq "ETH"} | select -expandProperty reward 
$ETH_price = $Minerstat | where{$_.coin -eq "ETH"} | select -expandProperty price
```

But I find no way to do that simple thing : `$ETH_proffit = ( $ETH_reward *  $ETH_price)`

Thanx ;)

Comment: my system uses the dot instead of the comma, so i had to change the comma to a dot ... but this >>> `$Test = iex "3.4488636215177E-12"; $Test.GetType().Name` <<< gives me `Double`.

Comment: You have a problem with the commas.  On the one hand, your number uses comma to separate the integer part from the fraction part.  On the other hand,  you use comma as the delimiter for your csv file.  Unless the double quotes surround the number in the csv file,  the comma is going to be read as a field separator, yielding garbage in the Import-csv.

Comment: You need to know whether your local culture uses comma or point as the decimal separator,  and which culture Powershell is using.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797798/understanding-the-get-culture-command

Comment: @WalterMitty That's not a problem, `epcsv` (aka. `Export-Csv`) automatically quotes column values

Comment: Good point.  I still wonder what get-culture would show the asker.  Is the decimal comma in the JSON file correct, and will Powershell interpret it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that PowerShell natively supports conversion from scientific notation - simply cast the value of the left-hand side argument to a `[decimal]` type, and the multiplication will work:

```
[decimal]$reward * $price
```

---

In order to convert individual properties using the pipeline, I'd suggest using `Select-Object`'s ability to "calculate" properties on the fly:

```
$minerstat = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://api.minerstat.com/v2/coins?list=BTC,ETH,ETC" | ConvertFrom-Json) | ? coin 

$coinsWithProfit = $minerstat |Select-Object @{Name='Reward';Expression={[decimal]$_.reward}},@{Name='Price';Expression={[decimal]$_.price}},@{Name='Profit';Expression={[decimal]$_.reward * $_.price}},Coin
```

Which not only converts the numbers to numerical types, it also calculates a `Profit` property in one go:

```
                        Reward         Price                         Profit Coin
                        ------         -----                         ------ ----
0.0000000000000000002712287173 10342.4638235 0.0000000000000028051731965696 BTC
   0.0000000000035190458817986  328.90981968 0.0000000011574487464280241201 ETH
     0.00000000026065858764466    4.87689492 0.0000000012712045419386171191 ETC
```